# I cannot call only links in the div with preg_match or preg_replace

Tags: php, curl, preg-replace, preg-match-all

**This is my code:**

```php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/');
$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

$html= curl_close($curl);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$regex = '/<nav class="hof-buttons">(.*?)<\/nav>/s';

if (preg_match($regex, $page, $list)) {
    echo  preg_replace("/<\\/?a(\\s+.*?>|>)/", "", $list[0])."<br />";
} else {
    print "Not found";  
}
```

I tried to get only the url name from the div tag. But it only gives me error. I want something like this in the main:

```
<div class="a"><a href="abc.php">a linki</a></div>
```

and in the codes it must be something like this:

```
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) ){}; 

echo  <a href="$list[1]"> $list[0]</a>;
```

But when I use this, it gives me error or no array. I want to have a code like that but how can I add what I want into the preg_match or how can I call the links in the div?

Comment: ops .. i typo wrong the place 
(and in the codes must be something like that into if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) ){};

echo $list[0];)

edited the place ; 

and in the codes must be something like that into if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) ){};

echo <a href="$list[0]">$list[1]</a>;

Comment: Please update question, rather adding comment here.

Comment: i dont know how to update friend O_O can u help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the entire solution (if this is what you're looking for).
And, btw., without *curl*, just *file_get_contents()* does it:

I took over your 3-step approach:

- Step 1: extract between <nav>…</nav>.
- Step 2: extract between <div>…</div> all *hrefs*.
- Step 3: gather text from different sources and clean it.

### Code

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/');

if($page===false) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

if ( preg_match_all('%<nav class=[\'"]{1,1}hof-buttons-set left[\'"]{1,1}>(.*?)</nav>%si', $page, $regs1, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ) {
    for ($x1 = 0; $x1 < count($regs1[0]); $x1++) {
        if ( preg_match_all('%<div.*?<a href=[\'"]{1,1}([^\'"]*?)[\'"]{1,1}>(.*?)</a>.*?</div>%sim', $regs1[1][$x1], $regs2, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ) {
            for ($x2 = 0; $x2 < count($regs2[0]); $x2++) {
            $link = $regs2[1][$x2];
            if (preg_match('/<img.*? title=[\'"]{1,1}(.*?)[\'"]{1,1}/sim', $regs2[2][$x2], $regs3)) {
                // No text, but image with title
                $text = $regs3[1];
            } elseif (preg_match('%<span.*?class=[\'"]{1,1}hof-label[\'"]{1,1}.*?>(.*?)</span>%sim', $regs2[2][$x2], $regs3)) {
                // Text in <span class="hof-label">...</span>
                $text = $regs3[1];
            } else {
                // Plain text
                $text = $regs2[2][$x2];
            }
                echo '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$link.'" target="_blank">' . trim($text) . '</a><br />';
            }    
        } else {
            echo '<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">HREF not found<span><br />';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">NAV not found<span><br />';
    exit;
}
?>
```

### Result

text: Women
 link:http://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/Women%27s+Designer+Clothing/03,default,sc.html
text: Dresses
link:http://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/women%27s+designer+dresses/301,default,sc.html
[....]

Comment: it gave error bro ;

can u give an example on my code ?

Comment: it worked like before but i dont wanna like that.. i want list link names something like that "ab.php?go=page" etc.

Comment: Update: the whole solution.

Comment: thank  u so much  bro it worked .. but there is no only the "class='hof-buttons' " the class full name;
 "class=hof-buttons-set left"

so how can i use empty character after "hof-buttons-set" this.. i must put "left" class too..

Comment: Made an update: _hof-buttons-set left_ (exactly "hof-buttons left") instead of _hof-buttons.*?_ (beginning with "hof-buttons" plus any text until the ending quote).

Comment: yep  bro :D can i ask one more question? how can i display the url names ? O_O u gave me only urls .. i hope i do not bother u so much O_O only i want display url names into the link O_O

Comment: So, the last update. It extracts the text in different variants (as they exist in the original web page), and creates appropriate hyperlinks. Note: **Stackoverflow is not a free coding service**! I urge you to **study the code** (mainly the regular expressions), and **try to understand**, and maybe enhance it. Otherwise this lesson would totally fail the goals of SO ... and maybe yours too.

Comment: but my question was not only link .. i asked what i need at header..link and link name.. so that ur work only give links.. my the other codes was giving link name.. thats why i asked can u help me ? T^T ..but anyways again thank u so much..

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a **link name**?